# get value from checkboxlist yii2

Tags: php, yii2

Here I got 2 views, first view is a form which let user to register. Then save information to DB in controller and refer to the other view.

I write a checkbox list in first view.

```
  <?= $form->field($model, 'items[]')->checkboxList(['a' => 'Item A', 'b' => 'Item B', 'c' => 'Item C']); ?>
```

Then I tried to get the value from it in controller and save to DB.

```
if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->validate()) {    
//save to DB
    $model = new EntryForm();
    $tableMember=new Members;
    $tableMember->select=$model-> items ;
    $tableMember->save();
    return $this->render('entry-confirm', ['model' => $model]);  
}
```

to show in entry-confirm.php

```
<li><label>Selected</label>: <?php echo Html::encode($model->items['a']) ?></li>
```

but it's empty.

I used NetBeans debugger, it shows:

```
$_POST = [
    '_csrf' => 'OTFHYUpIaVJNSxAJPBEDGV8DcTYjAhojAFofVx0HJmULVCwoAiRENA==',
    'EntryForm' => [
        'username' => 'df',
        'email' => '2@c.c',
        'password' => '123',
        'items' => [
            'a',
            'b',
        ],
        'country' => '',
    ],
];
```

It seems that items did get attributes. Is there the other way to create checkboxes? Or how can I get the values from a checkbox list?

Comment: I can see here is **DropDownList**, not a checkboxlist, it's typo  or anything else?

Comment: so sorry about that.. I paste the wrong part. already editted

Comment: please add controller action.

Comment: please refer this link......http://www.bsourcecode.com/2013/03/yii-chtml-checkboxlist/

Comment: `print_r($model->items)` in controller ?

Comment: @vishu It doesnt work, i think its for yii not for yii2?

Comment: @TouqeerShafi    I add echo in entry-confirm but empty as well

Comment: @J.H first of all specify your problem that you are getting post data of checked checkbox or not? if yes then it will be array you have to manage at the time of saving.

Answer (score 0):

try this way :

```
<?php
echo $form->checkBoxList($model,'items',
    array('a' => 'Item A', 'b' => 'Item B', 'c' => 'Item C'),                      
      );
?>
```

this checkbox list should be part of Form Widget, and Items should be your databse field or Variable in your class.First try to check your model fields are coming on your view or not.

Comment: hi thanks. but I even can't build the form in the view by this way

Comment: http://www.bsourcecode.com/yiiframework2/yii2-0-activeform-input-fields/    read this you will find solution for it.

Comment: yes, that's what i did

**<?php echo $form->field($model, 'name[]')->checkboxList(['a' => 'Item A', 'b' => 'Item B', 'c' => 'Item C']); ?>**

Comment: check in your controller that you are getting value from post or not.If not it means you have problem in your syntax in view.read documents of yii2 then try again.

Comment: now your question is more meaning full @jazz answer will be used if you want checkbox as array other wise you can use my example.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
 $tableMember->select = implode(",", $model-> items);
```

`$model->items` returns array of checked checkbox.

Comment: it shows
implode(): Invalid arguments passed
but i can see the value through NetBeans debugger

Comment: `print_r($model->items); exit()` try this in your controller action. what it gives? array of checked values?

Answer (score 0):

well, I always have issues getting back arrays with something like

`$model->items`

(as in values from e.g. checkboxlist), I find it easier to get the values with e.g. `$_POST['EntryForm']['items']`, like this:

`$model->items=implode(',',$_POST['EntryForm']['items']);`

(done in the controller, before `$model->save()`)

as an example:

(we split the post and save action)

```
if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {

      $model->items=implode(',',$_POST['EntryForm']['items']); //change items into string to be saved

    if($model->save()){

         return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);

            }

  } else {

      $model->items=explode(',',$model->items); //string to array to fill the checkboxlist

      return $this->render('create', [
          'model' => $model, 
      ]);
  }
```

the main issue for $model->items not to work is that probably it is not considered "safe", meaning that it has not been declared in the models under rules (public function rules(), e.g. adding

`[['items'], 'string', 'max' => 250],`

or

`[['items'], 'safe'],`

should do the trick....

see also: [Yii2 - Models - Safe Attributes](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-models.html)

HTH